# How to forcefully change the favicon icon when you update the Chrome Theme from white to black in Next.js 13.4.13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am working on a Next.js 13.4.13 application using App Router and I'd like to dynamically change the favicon based on the user's color scheme preference (dark or light mode). Currently, I have a black-colored favicon and a white-colored favicon. How can I set up my Next.js 13.4.13 app to automatically switch the favicon to the appropriate version when dark mode is activated and revert to the black version in light or default mode?

```
icons: {
    icon: [
      {
        media: '(prefers-color-scheme: light)',
        url: '/images/icon-dark.png',
        href: '/images/icon-dark.png',
      },
      {
        media: '(prefers-color-scheme: dark)',
        url: '/images/icon-white.png',
        href: '/images/icon-white.png',
      },
    ],
  },
```

I've applied this but this just affect when user change his windows color preference not working on when User changes it's chrome theme color.

So, I have read the official [docs about icons](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#icons) and I couldn't find the solution here.

Please give some code or part How Can I change the favicon base on Chrome Theme Customize